# Show that a monotone function has a fixpoint

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Let $F:\mathcal{P}(A)\to\mathcal{P}(A)$ be a monotone function, i.e. $X\subseteq Y\subseteq A$ implies $F(X)\subseteq F(Y)$. Show that it has a greatest fixpoint (i.e. a fixpoint $X$ such that for anybother fixpoint $Y$ we have that $Y\subseteq X$.
Hint: Consider $Z=\bigcup \{X\subseteq A | X\subseteq F(X)\}$, show that it is a fixpoint and then show that it is the greatest.

So far what I have is: $\forall X\in Z, X\subseteq F(X)\implies F(X)\subseteq F(F(X))$. This shows that $F(Z)\subseteq Z$, but I din’t know how to show that $Z\subseteq F(Z)$. I thought of using preimages to show that every $X\in Z$ can be written as $F(Y)$ for some $Y\in Z$, but I do not know if, for example, $X\subseteq F(X)$ implies $F^{-1}(X)\subset X$, I think that would be false since $F$ is an arbitrary function.

Someone care to help?

Comment: Assume z ∈ Z. Then z ∈ X ⊆ F(X) ⊆ A, for some X.  Notice that X  ⊆  Z. By monotinicity F(X)  ⊆  F(Z). So z ∈F(Z)

Comment: $X$ are subsets of $Z$, or elements of $Z$? I think I may be mistaken on that, but understood. Any hints on how to prove it is the greatest?

Comment: Since Z is the Union of a Set, for simplicity let Z =  $\bigcup \ Y $ Let z ∈ Z, by the definition of Union, we can find an X  such that z ∈ X ∈ Y. You need to show that X ⊆ Z ( In order to apply monotinicity)  Hint: What does it mean that X∈Y, use the definition. Hopefully this fulls in any gaps in my argument.

Comment: To show Z is the greatest fixpoint;  Assume Y is a fixpoint and that Z ⊆ Y. Try to show that Y ⊆ Z. Notice that since Y = F(Y), Y ⊆ F(Y).